# Is there any straight way to return the whole items of a Kendo DropdownlistFor using a single POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, dropdownlistfor

I'm using a kendo dropdownlistFor and populate it by items that a user is able to add. and I'm using a modal dialog which sends an ajax POST  to the controller. Now my question comes forward.
Is there any straight way (not using HiddenFor, or tricky Js or Jq stuffs. instead using MVC or Kendo functions) to pass the whole items of this DropdownList to the controller?

What I have now, is a kendo dropdownlistfor and a property of List. the Post returns, of course, the selected item id.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently trying to do a similar thing with my project.  As far as I have been able to discover there is no way to do this without having a JS function, ticket ongoing.  However your case may be possible if I understand it correctly.  The user passes in items to your dropdown correct?  So if you were to save those items into a List and then pass that list into the controller it should work correctly.  If you could give some of your code or a picture of your UI I may be able to give you a bit more direction.  Hope this helps!